# Local Area Connection State: Batch File

Tags: batch-file, networking, cmd

I am trying to write a batch script to identify whether or not the "Local Area Connection" adapter is plugged in or not.

```
    set nicValue=
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('netsh interface show interface "Local Area Connection"') do @set nicValue=%%a
echo %nicValue%
if "%nicValue%"=="Connect state:        Connected" echo On
```

I am able to get the right output and save it into a variable called `%nicValue%`, however, I am not able to run an 'if' command based off of this output.  As of right now, all I am trying to do is echo "On" if the batch file can see the "Connect state:" and "Connected", but I am at a loss.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: do `echo -%nicValue%-` and you will see why.

Comment: Stephan, I was able to find the trailing spaces.  However, I'm still unable to have the script run an "echo On" after it checks for the Connect State value.

Comment: One thing I noticed by typing in the command manually when the script gets started...by running the "if" command, I receive a "state: was unexpected at this time" error.

Comment: `state: was unexpected`: check your doublequotes (`"`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why don't you just filter the `:` and  in the `for /f` loop and get a clean value.  Like so:

```
    set nicValue=
for /f "tokens=3 delims=: " %%a in ('netsh interface show interface "Local Area Connection"') do @set nicValue=%%a
echo %nicValue%
if "%nicValue%"=="Connected" echo Connected
```

But I think your issue was using the `echo on` statement, as you're turning the `echo` to an `on` state, you need to rephrase that to something else like `echo Connected`

Comment: Attention, this is dependent of localzation. For example on german windows `connection state` is `Verbindungsstatus`, so `tokens=3` is not reliable on every computer